# Can publicly funded universities create areas designated for students of certain ethnicities only?

Tags: discrimination, state-university

Say a publicly funded university creates dedicated facilities, spaces and support for students of a particular ethnicity. They have signs like this:

> This is a Designated Area for <ethnicity  name> Students. Thank you

Is that legal anywhere?

(Inspired by [this news](https://www.stuff.co.nz/nz-news/350227767/act-accuses-university-segregation-opposition-strongly-disagrees))

Comment: South Africa had a similar policy. We called it Apartheid. Made us the most hated nation in the world. Just sound like segregation to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Its legal in many places

Most domestic laws against racial discriminations are implementing the UN [International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination](https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/international-convention-elimination-all-forms-racial). Article 1 says:

> 4. Special measures taken for the sole purpose of securing adequate advancement of certain racial or ethnic groups or individuals requiring such protection as may be necessary in order to ensure such groups or individuals equal enjoyment or exercise of human rights and fundamental freedoms shall not be deemed racial discrimination, provided, however, that such measures do not, as a consequence, lead to the maintenance of separate rights for different racial groups and that they shall not be continued after the objectives for which they were taken have been achieved.

In New Zealand, this provision exists in a number of forms but most relevantly here in [s73](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1993/0082/latest/whole.html#DLM304672) of the *Human Rights Act 1993* "Measures to ensure equality". Whether a particular instance fits the exemption is a matter for the Commissioner (or the courts).